# Playing Local video with Avplayer/kit Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

Whenever I run the project, it pulls up the video player, but the video doesn't play
[image: (the code and error)].
How do I fix this?  In case the code in the picture isn't clear enough, here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var avPlayer:AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from nib.

        let urlPathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "small", ofType: "mp4")

        if urlPathString != nil {

            let movieUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/kevingerman/Desktop/Pioneer News Season 2 Episode 1.mp4")

            self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: movieUrl as URL)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer

        }
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func playButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        //Trigger the video to play
        self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()    }


    }
```

}

Comment: Is the movie file included in your project?  
Open the Project Navigator (cmd - 1)
Then select your project root > your Target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.

Your video MUST be here. If it's not, then you should add it using the plus button

Comment: Why are you checking the string `urlPathString` for nil,  and then adding another URL for AVPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions suggested in the comment, and the one @Guan has answered are both correct.

Your `urlPathString` is actually nil here,

To make it work -

> 1- Either add the Target Membership, as suggested in the comment and the answer above or

Do the following

> 1.1- Delete the small.mp4 from bundle, make sure you `move it to trash`
>
> 2.1 - Go to trash and drag and drop your mp4 file into the project again, you will get a window like this -
> [image: Window on drag and drop]

While adding it back make sure you -

> Check the projectTarget checkbox like the screenshot below -
>
> [image: Checked box for app target]

**Make sure the file name is small.mp4**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `urlPathString` is not nil.
I don't know what the following code mean:

```
let movieUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/kevingerman/Desktop/Pioneer News Season 2 Episode 1.mp4")
```

I think the simulator can not get the path of file which in your mac.(I'm not sure, I haven't do this before).
You can check the file's target membership.

[image]

The code may work like this:

```
var urlPaht = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "small", withExtension:"mp4")
if urlPaht == nil {
        urlPaht = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/kevingerman/Desktop/Pioneer News Season 2 Episode 1.mp4")
}
self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: movieUrl as URL)
self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
```